# I can't figure out my mistake re-arranging this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions

Define:$$\varphi(s)=e^{-1}+e^{-2^s}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

and then

$$ e^{-2^s}\varphi(s)=e^{-(2^s+1)}+e^{-(2^{s+1})}+e^{-(2^s+3^s)}+e^{-(2^s+4^s)}+e^{-(2^s+5^s)}+\cdot\cdot\cdot $$

$$ e^{-2^s}\varphi(s)=e^{-(2^s+1)}+e^{-(2^{s+1})}+e^{-2^s}\big( \varphi(s)-e^{-1}-e^{-2^s}-e^{-3^s} \big)$$

$$ e^{-2^s}\varphi(s)=e^{-2^s}\varphi(s)-e^{-3^s} $$

$$ 0=-e^{-3^s} $$

I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrote$$ e^{-2^s}\varphi(s)=e^{-(2^s+1)}+e^{-(2^{s+1})}+e^{-2^s}\big( \varphi(s)-e^{-1}-e^{-2^s}-e^{-3^s} \big)$$you should have just written$$ e^{-2^s}\varphi(s)=e^{-(2^s+1)}+e^{-(2^{s+1})}+e^{-2^s}\big( \varphi(s)-e^{-1}-e^{-2^s} \big).$$